# Azure storage Rest Api File service

Tags: rest, file, azure-storage

I am trying to upload with Http request a file (not a blob) in Azure File service.

I have successfully uploaded a blob with Http request. I am using the same Authentication method (SharedKey). Inside documentation I found that I had to first create and then write a file.

> The Create File operation creates a new file or replaces a file. Note
>   that calling Create File only initializes the file. To add content to
>   a file, call the Put Range operation

Is it correct. Does anyone knows any other option. It seems a bit wrong to me. Does anyone has an example in .net?

(I even tried this workflow but i got a 400 error)

Comment: The documentation is correct. Please describe specifically what you have tried and what response you received. Also consider using the storage client library, which handles the details for forming the HTTP request for you. Here's a sample upload in .NET: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Samples/GettingStarted/VisualStudioQuickStarts/DataFileStorage/Program.cs#L108

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were expecting the Create File API works like Put Block Blob which uploads the content in the request body. Actually Create File is similar to Put Page/Append Blob. It requires you to initialize the resource first and then update the content. You can refer to the sample that @Michael pointed in the comment.